# How to remove percentage symbol from CircleProgress library - Material design Android

Tags: android, material-design

Has anyone worked with CircleProgress - Android Material Design  from this [Link](https://github.com/lzyzsd/CircleProgress)?

[image]

I'm working with ArcProgress from the mentioned link.

Here is my need,
On the above image contains number "**46**". Near to that number one **Percentage (%)** symbol there. I want to remove that percentage symbol.

How to remove it?
Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance....

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">

  <com.github.lzyzsd.circleprogress.ArcProgress
    android:id="@+id/arc_dBal"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    app:arc_bottom_text="Remaning"
    app:arc_finished_color="#ffff00"
    app:arc_progress="46"
    app:arc_text_color="00ffff"
    app:arc_unfinished_color="#2A50E4" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**main.java**

```
public class DataUsage extends Fragment {

  private ArcProgress arc_dBal,arc_validity;

  @Nullable
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main,null);

    arc_dBal     = (ArcProgress)view.findViewById(R.id.arc_dBal);
    arc_validity = (ArcProgress)view.findViewById(R.id.arc_validity);

    /*** CIRCLE PROGRESS ***/
    arc_dBal.setProgress(46);

    return  view;
  }
}
```

Comment: changed default_suffix_text = "%"; to default_suffix_text = " "; in ArcProgress.java as i never wanted it

Comment: use this attribute `<attr name="arc_suffix_text" format="string"/>`, btw you have the source file of `com.github.lzyzsd.circleprogress.ArcProgress` so just take a look how it works before asking on SO

Comment: @Veer3383 Thanks a lot. Its working fine...

Comment: glad to knw that it helped u

Answer (score 1):

Add this attribute to your xml code:

```
app:arc_suffix_text=""
```

Answer (score 0):

Change code:

1. In file (line 41) - delete "%" in donut: CircleProgress-master\library\src\main\java\com\github\lzyzsd\circleprogress\DonutProgress.java `private String suffixText = "%";` to: `private String suffixText = "";`
2. In file (line 30) - delete "%" in Circle: CircleProgress-master\library\src\main\java\com\github\lzyzsd\circleprogress\CircleProgress.java `private String suffixText = "%";` to: `private String suffixText = "";`
3. In file (line 85) - delete "%" in Circle: CircleProgress-master\library\src\main\java\com\github\lzyzsd\circleprogress\ArcProgress.java

`default_suffix_text = "%";`
to: 
`default_suffix_text = "";`

4. In file (line 36) - delete "%" in Circle: CircleProgress-master\library\src\main\java\com\github\lzyzsd\circleprogress\ArcProgress.java

`private String suffixText = "%";`
to: 
`private String suffixText = "";`

Comment: I really don't think the op really need to do that. Please read at line **suffixText = TextUtils.isEmpty(attributes.getString(R.styleable.ArcProgress_arc_suffix_text)) ? default_suffix_text : attributes.getString(R.styleable.ArcProgress_arc_suffix_text);**. It searching for suffix text attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best method but you can use :

```
:arc_suffix_text_size="0dp"
```